# Issue with included files like converters in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I have a very strange problem: InteliSense works fine, but when I want to build my project I see errors like

```
The name "NegationConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-  namespace:KinectAttractWindow.Converters".
```

This happens for every file that include other files, like `App.xaml`.

The source code of this project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/KinectAttractWindow)

Comment: Error visible in design mode only? Did application compile successfully?

Comment: Yes in visible mode also, but due this application won't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, the actually offending error is often something else. Once the compilation is in error state, it will cancel, so these namespace errors might just be by-products of an unfinished compiler pass. Try to check your error list for errors that make more sense to you.

I could not compile your solution because the Microsoft.Kinect assemblies are not included.

Comment: The worst thing is that there is no others errors ;/ but I will try to review code once again. To compile this project you need to have [Kinect SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=275588)